# What type of mathematics is this problem? (Scheduling maybe? I don't know what to search for to find help.)

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Sample Problem:

A well can supply 50 laborers per day.
40 laborers can build a new well in five days, up to 10 total.
Each laborer can complete 1 stone per day.
The new temple needs 5000 stones.
*** What is the most efficient way to get to 5000 stones?

This one is simple, but the idea can get very complex.  Is there a branch of mathematics that helps solve problems like this?  I don't know where to look to start studying.

Comment: discrete mathematics and optimization. Probably a graph theoretic way to model this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mathematical optimization.

You want to optimize (minimize) the number of laborers, so you can set up some criteria. And optimize the cost function.